# C GLFW How would I set a minimum size for a window?

Tags: c, window, min, glfw, window-resize

The title explains everything. Using the library GLFW from C, how could I keep the window width from going lower than 20 pixels across, or 10. How could I keep the height from reaching no more then 100? I tried making a callback function for when the window resizes that looks like this:

```
void windowResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glfwSetWindowSize(window, max(width, 50), max(height, 50));
}
```

However, when I reach the boundaries, my Mac throws a segmentation fault at my program. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are most likely "sliding" into the vortex by calling a window sizing function while a window sizing function is in progress. You would perhaps succeed by intercepting the sizing function, limiting the sizes, and passing on to the original handler.

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/555) that will most likely be included in GLFW 3.2. You can already test it out by compiling from the [devel branch](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/tree/devel).

Answer (score 3):

GLFW documentation has a solution using [`glfwSetWindowSizeLimits`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gac314fa6cec7d2d307be9963e2709cc90) which sets the minimum and maximum size the window content area can reach.

Usage:

```cpp
glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(window, 200, 200, 400, 400);
// min area is 200 by 200
// max area is 400 by 400

glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(window, 200, 200, GLFW_DONT_CARE, GLFW_DONT_CARE);
// min area is 200 by 200
// there is no maximum size
```

This function was added in GLFW 3.2.